# How to Add Horizontal line in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add a horizontal seperating line on a dynamic populated table.  How do I do this?   Below is a snippet.

```
    function addNewRow() {
    $('#displayTable tr:last').after('<tr><td style="font-size:smaller;" class="dataField1"></td><td style="font-size:smaller;" class="dataField2"></td><td style="font-size:smaller;" class="dataField3"></td></tr>');
    var $tr = $('#displayTable tr:last');
        $tr.find('.dataField1').text($('#txtName').val());
        $tr.find('.dataField2').text($('#txtAddress').val());
        $tr.find('.dataField3').text('document.write("<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><hr \/><\/td><\/tr>");
    }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged c# and java?

Comment: @jjnguy - Sorry about that :)

Comment: @user No worries, it is just helpful for everyone if you use the right tags.  I wasn't sure if you had a Java or C# component to your question.

Comment: What type of element is `dataField3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent `document.write` at all times, like everywhere unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Evil thing. Give this a shot:

```
$('#displayTable tr:last').after('<tr><td style="font-size:smaller;" class="dataField1"></td><td style="font-size:smaller;" class="dataField2"></td><td style="font-size:smaller;" class="dataField3"></td></tr>');
var $tr = $('#displayTable tr:last');
    $tr.find('.dataField1').text($('#txtName').val());
    $tr.find('.dataField2').text($('#txtAddress').val());
    $tr.find('.dataField3').append("<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><hr/><\/td><\/tr>");
```

Comment: '$tr.find('.dataField3').append' is what i was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would get rid of document.write. Instead of the

```
<hr>
```

you are using, put a "css class" that makes the table have a visible bottom border (line will be of course only as wide as the table itself). Something like

```
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
```